# Read variables of Amazon Elastic Beanstalk environment from the Procfile

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, java-8, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The problem is about the configuration params that the application needs to be executed in the JVM.  I defined the `XMX` and `XMS` environment variables but when deployed `procfile` can't read these variables.

`Procfile`:

> web: java $XMS $XMX  -jar application.jar

If I connect by `ssh` to the instance, I can't see my variables `$ XMX` and `$ XMS`.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: " I defined the XMX and XMS environment variables" -> Where? It's supposed to be in Configuration->Software (if done via console). https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html. Why not just add values to Procfile instead of variables?

Comment: To declare environment variables you need to use env prior to your `java` call, but if you need JVM parameters use -D with said variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to execute a script in the procfile, in that script it reads the environment variables, I still think something is doing wrong, but it works

Procfile:

> web: ./run.sh

Script run.sh

> exec java $JAVA_OPTS  -jar app.jar

JAVA_OPTS: environment variable defined in instance

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Procfiles can read from Elastic Beanstalk environment variables (at least as of AWS Linux 2 based platforms).  Just include them like you would in bash, like so:

```
web: command -opt1 $ENV_VAR -opt2 $ENV_VAR2
```

If you want to see your bash variables while ssh-ed in to the instance, you need to source your environment variable file in bash first:

```
# Load environment variables into bash
set -a; source <(sudo cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env)
# Now you can see your environment variables for debugging
echo #ENV_VAR
```